# How to embed escaped scss code in Jade

Tags: templates, pug, prepros

I'm using Prepros to compile *.jade templates.

**Current Jade code:**

```
pre
  code.hljs
    .ui-button {
      @include button;
      &.xs {@include button-size(xs);}
      &.sm {@include button-size(sm);}
      &.md {@include button-size(md);}
      &.lg {@include button-size(lg);}
      &.xl {@include button-size(xl);}
      &.xxl {@include button-size(xxl);}
    }
```

**Expected result:**

```
<pre>
  <code class="hljs">
.ui-button {
  @include button;
  &amp;.xs {@include button-size(xs);}
  &amp;.sm {@include button-size(sm);}
  &amp;.md {@include button-size(md);}
  &amp;.lg {@include button-size(lg);}
  &amp;.xl {@include button-size(xl);}
  &amp;.xxl {@include button-size(xxl);}
}
  </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

Code escaping wasn't required in case of CSS code.

```
pre
  code.hljs
    | .ui-button {
    |   @include button;
    |   &.xs {@include button-size(xs);}
    |   &.sm {@include button-size(sm);}
    |   &.md {@include button-size(md);}
    |   &.lg {@include button-size(lg);}
    |   &.xl {@include button-size(xl);}
    |   &.xxl {@include button-size(xxl);}
    | }
```